# Visual Studio, Entity Framework 6 and Oracle Integers

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio

Software we use:

- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Oracle 12C
- .Net 4.5.2
- Entity Framework 6.1.3
- Oracle managed dataaccess dll's 4.121.2.0 (don't know if this is relevant)

So, the problem here specifically is about integers. I have an Int in my table, the ID to be specific. The create script I used (through Visual Studio) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "OMT_VOG_UITVOERINGEN" 
(   "ID" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOT NULL ENABLE,
... <-- other columns --> ...
CONSTRAINT "OMT_VUN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
```

And some other stuff (Index, Foreign Key):

```
CREATE INDEX "OMT_VUN_VMN_FK" ON "OMT_VOG_UITVOERINGEN" ("VMN_ID");
ALTER TABLE "OMT_VOG_UITVOERINGEN" ADD CONSTRAINT "OMT_VUN_VMN_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("VMN_ID") REFERENCES "OMT_VOG_MOMENTEN"("ID") ENABLE;
```

(The max value of ID used to be 9 gazillion, but I changed it because I thought that was the problem and now it fits in an integer. Normally though, we use the maximum amount of nines there)

Now, after I create the table and go to Server Explorer, look the table up, and choose Design Table in the rightmouse button menu, I see this:
[image: Shows as number]

So the ID, that was created as an int, now shows as a number without a precision and with scale 0 (Number(*,0)). Which is confirmed when I generate the create script:

```
CREATE TABLE "OMT_VOG_UITVOERINGEN" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY etc....etc...
```

Looking the table up in Toad, the management software our oracle developers use, it shows as Integer.

So, as I was able to guess, EF6 generates that property as a Decimal. I can alter the type in the model, but I don't want to do that, because it gets generated every now and then when we add tables and such.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Oracle NUMBERs are base-10 floating point values with up to 38 digits of precision, so they should probably map to Decimal. If for some reason you really insist on limiting yourself to values compatible with signed 32-bit binary integers you can either use the BINARY_INTEGER or PLS_INTEGER types, which are defined in the package SYS.STANDARD. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That makes a lot of sense up to the point that Visual Studio is generating NUMBER(*,0) create scripts. That doesn't seem right to me. Anyway, I think I can work with this. The rest would be just curiosity.